# Django: top level project folder = root(nice short name), non-top level project folder = ? (nice short name needed)

Tags: python, django, naming-conventions

```
my_project(1)
├── my_project(2)
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

Names used to distinguish between the `my_project` folders:
`my_project`(1)
*Top level project folder*
*Project root folder*
*Root*

`my_project`(2)
*Non-top level project folder*

Do developers sometimes use another name for the *non-top level folder*? *Project root*/*root* is a relatively short and clear name. **I think it would be useful to have a name of similar length to indicate the other (non-root)folder**. (e.g. *project branch* (but that might create confusion with *git branches*)).

For people who say "just use *project folder* and *project root*": Suppose there hasn't been any need to mention the root folder and you want to immediately address the *non-root folder*? You'd have to use *non-top level folder* or list minimum one file or directory inside/next to it to be perfectly clear.

### Edit

Attempts at a good name will be listed here:
- `secondary` or `secondary_dir` but then I'd have to rename my `root` to `primary`/`primary_dir`.

Answer (score 3):

I typically do something like this:

```
andrews_app
├── andrews
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── another_module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── urls.py
└── manage.py
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is about how to uniquely indicate any of the two folders with exactly the same name. I don't even want to change what names the folders have in a project. (Why are you using *app* in your example?) I'm ok with both having the same name, I just think it would be useful to have an abstract name in order to easily communicate which folder you are talking about. It could also be useful in code. For example it's common to assign the path of the top level folder to a `root` variable. It would be valuable to also have a fitting variable name to the path of the non-top level folder.

Comment: Are you having issues from a namespace standpoint with relative imports? What kind of problems are you experiencing?

Comment: This is larger than just my inconvenience with it. But anyway, for me personally I need a good short name I can consequently use in my `settings.py` files that indicate the non-top level project folder.

Comment: So are you wanting to set a variable akin to MEDIA/STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: I would like to assign the non-hardcoded path of the non-top level project folder to a variable with a good short name I can keep using in further projects.

Comment: Normally, I usually talk in apps as well and what I mean about that is that every folder that DOES NOT contain settings.py, wsgi.py is a separate app and thusly are named stuff like 'core', 'exporter', 'profile' and so on. When the app you're writing grows I would want to have one folder name per project to avoid confusion. Just my two cents! :)

Comment: Not to be a smartass, but why not just call it `app`?

Comment: *That every folder that DOES NOT contain settings.py, wsgi.py is a separate app.* Off course, but the non-top level project folder I am talking about IS the one that does contain settings.py and wsgi.py.

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely not understanding your question.